# Migrating from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Azure AD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

Windows Server 2008 R2 (I am aware that it is out of support)  Active Directory Domain Controller and file server.

I am considering migrating users and files to Azure AD. Our users currently have Office365 (business basic or business standard) accounts, but they are not connected to their AD accounts.

Are there any tools that could automate part of this process? It appears that Microsoft only provides such tools for newer versions of Windows Server?

Can I somehow merge the Office365 and the old AD accounts?

Are there any other likely issues I will encounter?

Comment: `am aware that it is out of support` it's also off topic.

Comment: `Are there likely issue I will encounter?` nothing works with that product.

Comment: **Are there any tools that could automate part of this process?** - What process? You haven't stated what you're migrating. The server as a whole? The AD domain? The files? What? **Can I somehow merge the Office365 and the old AD accounts?** - Yes. With Microsoft Entra Connect Sync or Microsoft Entra Cloud Sync.

Comment: I am migrating the whole AD domain and files.

Comment: You can extend your on premises AD to Azure by deploying a Domain Controller VM in Azure. You can migrate your company/user files to Sharepoint Online/OneDrive or to Azure Files or to a file server VM in Azure.

Comment: Where do you are going to move the files?? to Sharepoint Online or Azure File?

Comment: all you need is to read their "hybrid identity" documents and have Azure AD Connect deployed